# Elegant way to manage a lot of fields of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, dictionary

I have a class which contains a lot of Lists:

```
private List<MyClass> m_List1;
private List<MyClass> m_List2;
private List<MyClass> m_List3;
private List<MyClass> m_List4;
...
private List<MyClass> m_ListN;
```

Everything is ok, but code is somehow getting complicated to read and to write... especially when I need to instanciate those lists when needed or clear them all.

Can you suggest me a good and elegant solution to manage them better? I was thinking about a `Dictionary<String, List<MyClass>>` that can act as a kind of "wrapper" for all my lists or, even better, a class with an internal `Dictionary<String, List<MyClass>>` that exposes a method `ClearAll()`, for example...
In that case, how should I deal with list replacements, clearing, disposing and so on? Let's say I have the following code in my wrapper...

```
public void Assign(String key, List<MyClass> value)
{
    m_InternalDictionary[key] = value;
}
```

If another list already exists on that key, should I clear it before replacing it with another one?

Any other suggestion?

Comment: How about an array of Lists? `List<MyClass> [] m_Lists` ?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List<MyClass>>` or, seeing as the field names differ by a number, even a `List<List<MyClass>>` seem like the way to go.

Comment: Whats wrong with `List<List<MyClass>> m_Lists;`? How are you using those lists and which functionality do you expect from wrapper?

Comment: I second the Dictionary thought, because he may want to do something to a specific list and it would be easier to get to `myDictionary["m_List1"]` with it.

Comment: (Generally, when you have "lot of X of the same type", you should immediately think of a collection.)

Comment: Or, similarly, a List of Lists -> `List<List<MyClass>>` ... although I would prefer a `Dictionary` as you said which will probably give a bit more flexibility in the future...

Comment: Problem is that every list has a different role in my code or is used inside a different function. That's why a list of lists can't work. I must recover exactly THAT list at THAT moment... not a random one or an indexed one.

Comment: I could move this to our code review SE site. Flag or @ ping me if you'd like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason why you need to have separate lists? Why not just have a member in your class that is a list of lists?

```
private List<List<MyClass>> myClasses { get; set; }
```

Comment: Problem is that every list has a different role in my code or is used inside a different function. That's why a list of lists can't work. I must recover exactly THAT list at THAT moment... not a random one or an indexed one.

Comment: are they all MyClass? Or are they sub-types of MyClass? You could generate a Dictionary with types as keys if that is the case. Otherwise, I guess you could use a Dictionary with string keys, but it seems like there is probably a better way to do what you want. Without more details though, it's hard to give you a better solution.

Comment: Only MainClass is being used in my lists.